# State undefined when I try to use in <h2>tag in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

here is code

```
const [wordList, setwordList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/chapterList').then((response) => {
            setwordList(response.data)

        });
    }, [])
```

and what I want to make is

```
return (
        <div className="Doughnut">
            <h2>{wordList[0].id}</h2>
            <Doughnut data={doughnutData} />
        </div>
      );
```

problems here. I have already checked that **wordList[0].id** is not undefined, and this gives right value. But when I try to use in h2 tag, it is undefined. I thinks this is because webpage renders before wordList[0] gets value.

what is cause of the problem and How can I solve it?

Comment: `useEffect()` runs after the first render, therefore at the very beginning `wordList[0]` is undefined. You should change `<h2>{wordList[0].id}</h2>` to `<h2>{wordList.length > 0 && wordList[0].id}</h2>` so that the ID is printed only if `wordList` contains at least one item

Comment: just add optional chaining like wordList?.[0]?.id or (wordList.length && wordList[0].id)

Comment: @Javvy7 `wordList` is an array; I do not think you can do `wordList?.[0]` and, in any case, it would be unnecessary as `wordList` is initialized to `[]` therefore it is granted not to be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could initialize the state as: `useState([{ id: 'UNKNOWN' }]);`

Comment: @Javvy7 Furthermore, the optional chaining would avoid to throw an error but would still return `undefined`.

Comment: @Javvy7 I thinks your right. it worked as I intented. thanks